# Visual Studio 2008 error while debugging an app with "uiAccess=true" in the manifest

Tags: visual-studio, manifest

I have a C# WinForms application that has "uiAccess" set to "True" in it's manifest file. When I try to start/debug it in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 under Windows 7 x64 (RTM) I get this error:

> Running an Accessibility application requires following the steps described in Help.

The help button is a broken link, and clicking ok just closes the application. It is digitally signed, and I can start it just fine in Windows Explorer. Here is the same bug in MS Connect, but unfortunately it's closed:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=384183

**Question:** Can anyone else using Vista/Win7 x64 (with UAC enabled) confirm that they experience the same problem? Has anyone seen this problem before and have any idea how to work around it?

Comment: Is anyone willing/able to reproduce this problem? I would love to know if it's just me, or if it's an actual issue with VS2008.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that Visual Studio 2013 has finally fixed this issue, for anyone still suffering from this bug.  :)

Comment: I'm still seeing the same issue on VS 2013 Update 3. It's not fixed.

Comment: 2019 and cant run it

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Visual Studio with administrators privileges. (Just right-click on it's icon and click on **Run As Administator**.

When you run Visual Studio with administrative privileges, any process created by it will have administrative rights and UAC will not appear. So when you debug you applications it will have privileges by default.

Comment: I am running VS as an administrator using the technique you described. This isn't a prompt asking me if I want to run the application, VS is telling me it can't run it and not providing any more information.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Note that this was after VS had already supposedly detected that it needed to be run as administrator, and had relaunched itself accordingly, and I had to click through a UAC prompt - still no go. The compatibility checkbox HAD to be set manually.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a C++ app trying to run from dev studeio.  I set UAC Bypass UI Protection back to false in the project settings, then changed UAC Execution Level to requireAdministrator, and that seems to fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I get this same issue with a similar set up but using VS2012.

I found this "solution", it doesn't help me, but maybe it will help you

Basically you need to run an elevated debugger, and start it once your app starts:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/7a42efab-5ce8-456f-8a58-dfedbc2cefcb/debugging-with-uiaccesstrue?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation

Answer (score 0):

Choose the created exe file and make the file writable, i.e. unchecked read-only.